# How can i make use of DOM Create Element to make the existing code more dynamic and concise?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have built a utility which gathers users input data and then I am downloading the data in form of a YAML file. The format of the data is very particular, and hence I had to create data and hack in spaces to bring it to a proper format. This code is working fine till Number of Chais=2, now the problem is if the number of chasis will be increased to let's say 10 or 20 then the code will be so bulky and would consume a lot of memory. Hence can anyone tell me how I can make use of the DOM Create Elements to make this utility more dynamic? Attaching the code where the data is being formatted. 
Attaching the entire code in the fiddle as the entire code is not fitting in here.
Any help is much appreciated

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const extra = {};

        const oForm = document.forms.myForm;
        const oSave = document.querySelector('input[name="save"]');
        const oSub = document.querySelector('input[name="submit"]');
        const oCtrl = document.querySelector('select[name="controller"]');
        const oTest = document.querySelector('select[name="test"]');
        const oProto = document.querySelector('select[name="protocol"]');
        const oiSCSI = document.querySelector('select[name="iSCSIip"]');
        //const oTmp = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent")
        const oTmp = document.getElementById("extra")

//formatting Data according to the contstraints of Controllers, 
var step = oForm.chassis.value;

    let payload = '';
    //Creating the data elements to be cpatured in the downloaded yaml file 

    for (let i = 0; i < step; i++) {
    //  console.log('Walking east one step');

        payload+= '\n -  # UUT ' + i + ' configuration'+'\n    -  # Chassis ' + i + ' configuration'+ String.fromCharCode(10);

        const addToPayload = (object, whitespace) => {

        for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
            payload += key + '\n';
            const details = object[key];
            for (const key1 of Object.keys(details)){
            const value = details[key1];
            str=value[0];
            com=value[2];
            val=value[1];
            whitespace=value[3];
            var input= JSON.stringify(val);

    }   
        }
        }

    if((document.getElementById("ip1").disabled || document.getElementById("ip2").disabled) && oForm.ctrls.value==1){
    if(i==0){
    let data = {
        "   PDU:": {
          "PDU_IP":['       PDU_IP',' '+ oForm.ip.value,"   #PDU IP",'  '+'\n'],
          "PDU_LEFT":['     PDU_LEFT',[oForm.lo.value]," # left_outlet(s) ",'   '+'\n'],
          "PDU_RIGHT":['        PDU_RIGHT',[oForm.ro.value]," # right_outlet(s) ", '    '+'\n']
        },  
        "   \n  CONTROLLER: # Controller settings ": {          
            "Controller_ID#1": ["       -  # Controller A for RBOD/EBOD"],
            "Netmask IP_A":["           MC_IP",' '+document.getElementById('mc_ip').value,'  # RBOD MC IP',''+'\n'],
            "MC_Netmask_A": ["          MC_Netmask",' '+document.getElementById('netmask_ip1').value,'  # RBOD MC Netmask',''+'\n'],
            'MC_Gateway_A':['           MC_Gateway',' '+document.getElementById('gateway_ip1').value,'  # RBOD MC Gateway',''+'\n'],
            'MC_A': ['          MC',' '+document.getElementById('rbod_mc1').value,'  # RBOD MC port',''+'\n'],
            'SC_A':['           SC',' '+document.getElementById('rbod_sc1').value,'  # RBOD SC port',''+'\n'],
            'FU_A':['           FU',' '+document.getElementById('rbod_fu1').value,'  # RBOD FU port',''+'\n'],
            'EC_A':["           EC",' '+document.getElementById('rbod_ec1').value,'  # EC port on RBOD or GEM port on JBOD',''+'\n'],
            'Controller_ID#2': ["           ID",' '+document.getElementById('Controller_ID1').value,"   #Controller ID, A or B",''+'\n'],   
        }
      };
      addToPayload(data, ' ' );
        }

    if(i==1){
            let data1 = {
        "   PDU:": {
          "PDU_IP":['       PDU_IP',' '+ oForm.ip.value,"   #PDU IP",'  '+'\n'],
          "PDU_LEFT":['     PDU_LEFT',[oForm.lo.value]," # left_outlet(s) ",'   '+'\n'],
          "PDU_RIGHT":['        PDU_RIGHT',[oForm.ro.value]," # right_outlet(s) ", '    '+'\n']
        },  
        "   \n  CONTROLLER: # Controller settings ": {          
            "Controller_ID#1": ["       -  # Controller A for RBOD/EBOD"],
            "Netmask IP_A":["           MC_IP",' '+document.getElementById('mc_ip_1').value,'  # RBOD MC IP',''+'\n'],
            "MC_Netmask_A": ["          MC_Netmask",' '+document.getElementById('netmask_ip1_1').value,'  # RBOD MC Netmask',''+'\n'],
            'MC_Gateway_A':['           MC_Gateway',' '+document.getElementById('gateway_ip1_1').value,'  # RBOD MC Gateway',''+'\n'],
            'MC_A': ['          MC',' '+document.getElementById('rbod_mc1_1').value,'  # RBOD MC port',''+'\n'],
            'SC_A':['           SC',' '+document.getElementById('rbod_sc1_1').value,'  # RBOD SC port',''+'\n'],
            'FU_A':['           FU',' '+document.getElementById('rbod_fu1_1').value,'  # RBOD FU port',''+'\n'],
            'EC_A':["           EC",' '+document.getElementById('rbod_ec1_1').value,'  # EC port on RBOD or GEM port on JBOD',''+'\n'],
            'Controller_ID#2': ["           ID",' '+document.getElementById('Controller_ID1').value,"   #Controller ID, A or B",''+'\n'],   
        }
            };
        addToPayload(data1, ' ' );
}
    }

//Converting the data into a yaml file and downloading it on button click
      const blob = new Blob([payload], {
        type: 'text/yaml'
      });


      var file =  oForm.test.value + "_" + oForm.protocol.value + "_UUT_Config" + '.yaml';

      let link = document.createElement('a');
      link.download = file;

      if (window.webkitURL != null) {
        link.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
      } else {
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
      }
      link.click();
    }

      oCtrl.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
      oTest.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
      oSave.addEventListener('click', savehandler);
      })
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayashri/gc4z137e/2/)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have minimized the code. I have attached the fiddle to show how the data is downloaded as well. Sorry for the length of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using separate IDs for each element, consider using classes instead. For example, rather than using

```
document.getElementById('mc_ip').value
```

on the first iteration, and

```
document.getElementById('mc_ip_1').value
```

on the second iteration, instead create a *class* of `mc-ip`s, like:

`<input class="mc_ip">`

Use that same pattern everywhere - change the IDs to classes, and have each separate "section" use the same class name for the same types of inputs. Then, instead of using a repetitive

```
if(i==1){
  // lots of code referencing _1
```

to check what you can call `addToPayload` with, simply access

```
collection[i]
```

For example:

```
const mcIps = document.querySelectorAll('.mc-ip');
const mcNetmasks = document.querySelectorAll('.netmask_ip1');
const mcGateways = document.querySelectorAll('.gateway_ip1');
const mcAs = document.querySelectorAll('.rbod_mc1');
// ...

const data = {  
  "   PDU:": {  
    "PDU_IP":['       PDU_IP',' '+ oForm.ip.value,"   #PDU IP",'  '+'\n'],  
    "PDU_LEFT":['     PDU_LEFT',[oForm.lo.value]," # left_outlet(s) ",'   '+'\n'],  
    "PDU_RIGHT":['        PDU_RIGHT',[oForm.ro.value]," # right_outlet(s) ", '    '+'\n']   
  },    
  "   \n  CONTROLLER: # Controller settings ": {            
    "Controller_ID#1": ["       -  # Controller A for RBOD/EBOD"],  
    "Netmask IP_A":["           MC_IP",' '+mcIps[i].value,'  # RBOD MC IP',''+'\n'],    
    "MC_Netmask_A": ["          MC_Netmask",' '+mcNetmasks[i].value,'  # RBOD MC Netmask',''+'\n'], 
    'MC_Gateway_A':['           MC_Gateway',' '+mcGateways[i].value,'  # RBOD MC Gateway',''+'\n'], 
    'MC_A': ['          MC',' '+mcAs[i].value,'  # RBOD MC port',''+'\n'],  
  // ...

  // ...

};
addToPayload(data, ' ');
```

Comment: I edited my code and have added in the above part. Although the data which I am getting in the first iteration is proper, i am not getting any data in the second iteration. I replaced ids with class names and used query selectors to look for the classes. can you please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "Not getting any data", do you mean that the nothing is selected past the `[0]`th index in the collection? (if so, then you need to change *all* the sections so that each field uses classes, not just the first section)

Comment: I changed all the fields of contents of both the tabs. Still I am facing the same issue. Attached the code below your comment for reference.

Comment: What do you mean, "the same issue"? The original issue was the repetitiveness of the code - using classes instead should fix that. What do you mean by "not getting any data" for the later iterations? Do you mean that the `[1]`st etc indicies are `undefined`? (if so, you need to change *all* sections to use classes, not just the first one)

Comment: It worked fine now, I replaced [i] with [i+1]. Now there is a problem though that how to populate the _B elements. I have to give them different class names? Becuase i tried giving different class names for them but its saying undefined value.

Comment: You can follow the exact same pattern. An `i` of `0` uses, eg: `document.getElementById('mcip').value`, and an `i` of `1` uses `document.getElementById('mcip_2').value`. So just get rid of the IDs and use classes instead: `document.querySelectorAll('.mcip')[i].value`

Comment: If you do that but get undefined, then you haven't changed all of the IDs to classes in all of the sections